# res.clearCookie function doesn't delete cookies

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, express, cookies

I am creating an authorization system for my express (with typescript) application and I use JWT and save them into cookies to keep the user logged in. I have a problem with the logout part and res.clearCookie() doesn't delete cookies.

I have used cookie-parser in the index file and I have tried resetting the cookie with an empty value or expiration date of now but it doesn't work for me. As I stated above res.clearCookie("jwt") doesnt work either. All dependencies are up-to-date.

Login and Login Verification works fine and I can set and read [and decode] the JWT properly.

**Main Part of Login Code**

```
res.cookie("jwt", token, {
   httpOnly: true,
   expires: new Date(
       Date.now() + 1000 * 86400 * stayLoggedInDays
   )
}).send("Message: Login successful");
```

**Logout Code**

```
router.post(
  "/logout",
  (req, res, next) => {
    res.clearCookie("jwt");
    next();
  },
  (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.cookies);
    res.end("finish");  
  }
);
```

After Logout I still can see the user profile but if I delete the cookie manually from postman the profile page won't show any information so my conclusion is that express cannot clear cookies.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I believe your issue is that you are not passing the `options` parameter into `clearCookie()` and the client is not clearing the cookie as it is not identical.  Per the [Express documentation](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.clearCookie):

> Web browsers and other compliant clients will only clear the cookie if the given options is identical to those given to res.cookie(), excluding expires and maxAge.

Also found a [GitHub issue on the express repo](https://github.com/expressjs/express/issues/691#issuecomment-385054381) which states the same and shows an example of passing the domain and path:

```
res.clearCookie('my_cookie', {domain: COOKIE_DOMAIN, path: COOKIE_PATH});
```

Comment: i've got bot domain and path but still not deleteing

Comment: same settings also work for Fastify server, at least as of today :)

Comment: I have use `httpOnly` and `secure` in options for `res.cookie`. Should i add them in `res.clearCookie` as well ?

Comment: @yusuf It seems to be so, if you used that in `res.cookie` call. Also if you used `sameSite` attribute on `res.cookie` options, it must match at `clearCookie` options.

Comment: @KoteIsaev I'm afraid it's also not working.

Comment: it's not supposed to work, this is meant to annoy the living hell out of developers

Answer (score 0):

From the frontend logout API call include the `withCredentials: true` and `credentials: "include"`

```
// Axios logout request
export const logout = async () => {
  return await api.post(
    "/logout",
    {},
    {
      withCredentials: true,
      credentials: "include",
    }
  );
};
```

This is what worked for me, hope that helps!

**Edit:**

If you have configured CORS as below on your backend server, the above answer is applicable. Else you can omit the **credentials: "include"** from your axios API call.

```
app.use(
  cors({
    origin: process.env.CORS_ORIGIN,
    credentials: true,
  })
);
```

Comment: this gave me CORS errors

Comment: Can you please share your CORS setup code on JSBin so that I can help?

Comment: I managed to fix my issue, I posted the solution in another question here... nevertheless, `credentials: "include"` was not necessary. I'm using `axios`

Comment: That makes sense, it's needed only if one has configured CORS with `credentials: include`. Anyway, thanks for the update!