# express-session cookie still exist despite logout

Tags: node.js, express, express-session

I have this `logout route` with expressJS using `express-session` :

```
router.post('/logout', (req, res) => {
  req.session.user = null;
  req.session.destroy((err) => {
    if (err) {
      return res.status(400).end();
    } else {
      return res.status(200).end();
    }
  });
});
```

Although **the user is logged out Correctly and the `sid` changes, The cookie still exists!!** which freaking me out.

I want to completely remove the `cookie` to calm my heart.

This is the `config` of the `express-session` package

```
app.use(
  session({
    store: new MariaDBStore({
      pool: require('./config/db_pool')
    }),
    name: 'sid',
    secret: process.env.KEY,
    saveUninitialized: false,
    resave: false,
    cookie: {
      path: '/',
      httpOnly: true,
      secure: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development' ? false : true
    }
  })
);
```

Comment: This is by design. But you can clear the cookie with res.clearCookie.

Comment: I tried it and it does not work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I git the answer from @Joe comment above and this like

[Answer from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57791209/res-clearcookie-function-doesnt-delete-cookies)

using this close completely removes the cookie.
the options of `res.clearCookie` are not optional .

```
  res.clearCookie('sid', { path: '/' });
```