# how to delete cookie form frontend using express JS server

Tags: reactjs, express, cookies, backend, access-token

Trying to delete cookie in frontend using express JS server but cookie is not deleted from frontend.

I am trying to make a function from expressjs backend to logout by deleting access_token from frontend.

Here is code from backend:

```
export function logout(req, res) {
  res.clearCookie("access_token", { httpOnly: true })
  const token = req.cookies.access_token;
  if (token) return res.status(400).json("Logout Failed");
  return res.status(200).json("Logout SuccessFully")
}
```

here is frontend with react code:

```
async function logout() {
    try {
      await axios.post("http://localhost:8000/api/user/logout", { withCredentials: true, credentials: "same-origin" })
      // setCurrentUser(null)
      console.log("logout")
    } catch (error) {
      setAlert({ isShow: true, message: error.message, duration: 3000, type: "error" })
      console.log(error)
    }
  }
```

In network section of console access_token is removed but still visible on application tab.

How can I remove token from frontend by calling route of express JS.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57791209/res-clearcookie-function-doesnt-delete-cookies